# What collider would be perfect?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my problem is that no of the colliders im using work 100% of the time. I am making a game where you basically jump from one planet to another while the the planets are slowly rotating.

I've tried to use different colliders such as a box circle edge colliders and change the collision detection to continuous and also tried to change the "Fixed Timestep" in project settings.

My player has two box colliers, one Ground check and another so it doesn't fall though the planets, and a basic move script with screen shake and particle effects.

Comment: Surely this is a trial and error for your specific use case?

Comment: Although I would think that a capsule collider would be better than a box collider for the player when landing on a sphere?

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a perfect collider in any GameEngine, because of the High-performance penalty that they would have.

In order to ensure a perfect collider, you need to make it yourself.

The best way would be to use your coordinate system and object size to ensure that there is no clipping, but that would only work for single primitives.

Another approach would be to shoot ray cast, at all "closest" objects, and depending on the speed of both objects, their velocity and other parameters, decide what to do in "incoming frame" because you would know based on all the parameters and a bit of math, that you would collide with this entity.

(There will be no code example, as such implementation would be huge and probably very project-specific)

Further reading [Octtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree)